# I can't get feedback on my comment from the Google play store

Tags: google-play-store

So I commented on Smule Sing! App and I gave it two stars. Everything was normal until I got feedback on my comment from Smule. I got an email and I tried to click on the link but it wouldn't let me, the link didn't even stand out it just looked like regular text. I tried everything but I can't find the feed back, what should I do??

Answer (score 2):

If you have a problem with an app and you'd like a response from the developer, the best thing to do is always to contact them directly. You can find contact details (usually a support email address) on the app's store page.

Reviews are the worst way to get help with a problem. The app developer isn't notified of all new reviews, so unless they have a tool that automatically checks for new reviews, they might not see your review for some time, especially for a popular app with lots of reviews. In addition, the length of the review and their response is very limited, so it's probably not possible to get/give enough information to help solve the problem.

On top of that, if you give a bad review saying that something doesn't work, and it turns out to be simple mistake, it makes you look like a fool, right where everyone can see. This is even more of a consideration now that Google Play displays your name next to the review, and uses your reviews to recommend apps to your friends.

If you do leave a review on an app and the developer responds, the reply shows up right next to your review on the app's store page. If you've had a notification but there's no reply there, it's possible that the developer wrote a reply but subsequently deleted it, perhaps because it no longer applies to the latest version of the app.